# Javascript - Calculate time from the rawOffset Google timezone API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, datetime, google-api, google-maps-timezone

I am developing an application to get the local time of city. I am using google Geocode API to get the latitude and longitude of a city and the same is passed to the timezone API.

*Time Zone API return the following*

```
{
"dstOffset" : 0,
"rawOffset" : 0,
"status" : "OK",
"timeZoneId" : "Europe/London",
"timeZoneName" : "Greenwich Mean Time"
}
```

I need to calculate the time for the following. From this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15776424/google-map-time-zone-get-local-time), I got the following code to get the local time from `rawOffset`.

```
function calcTime(offset) {
var d = new Date();
var utc = d.getTime() + (d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
var nd = new Date(utc + (3600000*offset));

alert("The local time is " + nd.toLocaleString());
}
calcTime(-28800.0);
```

But this is having one hour delay in time for cities like `London, Washington, NewYork` and returns correct time for `Arizona`.

Also. I am not aware of this relation between `local time` and `rawOffset` parameter to calculate the time. Please explain what this `rawOffset` parameter is and how to fix this one hour time delay for some cities.

In Google TimeZone API [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/), I read that

> The local time of a given location is the sum of the timestamp parameter, and the dstOffset and rawOffset fields from the result.

What is the timestamp parameter here? I couldn't give anything other than `1331161200`.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

*FIX* : This is because I am passing `timestamp` parameter as `1331161200` in the timezone API. When I replaced timestamp with the following code, I am getting correct response from the Google APIs with dstOffset and rawOffset.

```
myDate = new Date('1/1/1970');
timeStamp = myDate.getTime();
```

Can anyone give me the technical explanation of how it worked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't considered the Daylight Savings Time offset, which is why certain cities are off by an hour.

```
calcTime(rawOffset+dstOffset);
```

Timestamp contains both the date and time for as DST is only occurs in certain periods of the year.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10428184/3583980

Comment: The dstOffset returned is also '0'. Consider for Washington the rawOffset returned now is -18000 and dstOffset is 0 and the calcTime return 4:13AM but the actual time is 5:26AM

Comment: I suspect it's only the date that's giving DST confusion. Encode today's date and time using http://www.esqsoft.com/javascript_examples/date-to-epoch.htm and put this in for the timestamp for the API.

Comment: I have updated the question, please check. The issue is fixed. This was due to the timestamp I passed to the timezone API.

Comment: You had hardcoded a date that occurred in the past (Wed Mar 07 2012 23:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)) with no DST as the timestamp.

    `myDate = new Date();
    timeStamp = myDate.getTime();`

Comment: It is not due to the past, I guess. The TimeStamp must be for 1/1/1970. When I did new Date('1/1/1970') it worked. So, is the timestamp browser dependent.? I think the timestamp that I hard coded is not for my timezone which caused the issue.

Comment: myDate = new Date(); timeStamp = myDate.getTime(); gives me an error from the API. The timestamp must be for 1/1/1970

Comment: You don't need to specify a value when creating the myDate object as `myDate.getTime()` sets the value of myDate to the current epoch (see the link I posted to encode/decode timestamp.

Comment: Thanks! The epoch value from the link got worked. Is there any script to get the current epoch?

Comment: It's getTime() as mentioned in the answer I linked to http://stackoverflow.com/a/10428184/3583980